# mocking IUserPasswordStore<TUser> using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have `ChangePassword` method where I have `UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, oldPassword, newPassword);` to change password'.

**Problem**: Above line gives the following error.

> System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement
>   IUserPasswordStore.

**ChangePassword method line of code**

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, oldPassword, newPassword);
```

**Unit Test**

```
var mock = new Mock<MyController>();
mock.CallBase = true;
var obj = mock.Object;

obj.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext { Request = new HttpRequestMessage() };
obj.Request.SetOwinContext(CommonCodeHelper.mockOwinContext());

IPrincipal user = GetPrincipal();
obj.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = user;
var result = await obj.ChangePassword(dto);
```

**IOwinContext mocking code**

```
public static IOwinContext mockOwinContext()
{
    var owinMock = new Mock<IOwinContext>();
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.Authentication.User).Returns(new ClaimsPrincipal());
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.Request).Returns(new Mock<OwinRequest>().Object);
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.Response).Returns(new Mock<OwinResponse>().Object);
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.Environment).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "key1", 123 } });
    var traceMock = new Mock<TextWriter>();
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.TraceOutput).Returns(traceMock.Object);

    var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
    userStoreMock.Setup(s => s.FindByIdAsync("User1@test.com")).ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser
    {
        Id = "User1@test.com",
        FirstName = "Test",
        LastName = "User1",
        Email = "User1@test.com",
        UserName = "User1@test.com",
    });
    var appManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStoreMock.Object);
    owinMock.Setup(o => o.Get<ApplicationUserManager>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(appManager );
    return owinMock.Object;
}
```

After getting above error, I tried to mock `IUserPassword` inside `IOwinContext code block (above method)` using following line of code

```
var passwordManager = userStoreMock.As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

I think the above mocking code for IUserPassword isn't correct becuase now it gives exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.

How do I mock `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>`?

Comment: @Aleksey L any idea please

Comment: @Nkosi Any help please

Comment: This is why I abstracted identity functionality behind interfaces I control. The problems you are having show higher level issues with the design of your system. You are relying on too many implementation details which are now giving you problems to mock. There is not much I can help you with given the bits and pieces you have sprinkled throughout your examples.

Comment: Probably, i wanted to ask in short way. 'How do i mock 'IUserPasswordStore' and 'IUserEmailStore' inside 'IUserStore'?

Comment: Abstract `UserManager` behind a custom interface you control and work forward from there. Microsoft would have mocked and tested Identify framework extensively before releasing it. No need for you to mock and retest it. You shouldn't be concerning yourself with such low level semantics.

Comment: I know this is an old question but for some who might have the same question ...

var mockStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            var passwordManager = mockStore.As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            var _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockStore.Object);